# Request: Way of avoiding TextView and ImageViews because of the amount of Text and Images

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

i am learning to code in Android Studio. I want to build a guide, with different fragments, called through a navigation drawer.

**What I want to do and my issue:**
Each fragment will describe different topics, therefore I will probably use a spinner to access those differnt topics.

**What I am asking for:**
Each topic will have a lot of text and images, what is the best way for me to tackle the problem?

**My own ideas:**

- Set up new fragments in the fragment, which will get called via the `getChildrenFragmentManager()` through the choice in the spinner. From what I found out, it is not the best way to use fragments in fragments and it also seems like an overkill. Do you have suggestions?
- Using HTML to provide a more convinient way of setting up the guides instead of using 10 textviews followed by imagesviews each time.

I am very open to suggestions and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Even though people think this is a bad question I will answer it myself:

I am storing my textsheets in folders which only contain my strings now in a `HTML` format.
After research I figured out that it would make more sense to use **`WebView` instead of `TextViews`** since those work better with displaying **`HTML`** text.

Furthermore I use the following codes to **display my pictures inside the HTML** code.

```
<body><center><img src="file:///android_res/drawable/logo_behaviour.png" width= 60% height = auto align="middle"></center></body>
```

For displaying images inside my HTML strings.

Peace Out!